# How to encrypt the post request body content?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I have a login service class which will call a http post request and get's the token in response. My problem is when the request fails it will print the body content in console which includes the password to login to application. How do I encrypt this password and users won't be able to see it in log.

```
export class Login {
      perform(username: string, password: string, url:string){
              return cy.request({
                   method: 'POST',
                   url: "https://fake.com",
                   body: `grant_type=password&scope=FULL_VIEW&username=${id}&password=${password}`
             }).then(response => {
                   expect(200).toequal(response.status);
}
```

Comment: You could create an .env file which holds an encryption key, no one can see this file and only the server can read it. Then the server uses the pattern or sequence to decrypt or encrypt the response as it is sent one way or another. Also couldn't you simply not log the error to the console?

Comment: @Cohen do you have any reference to this ?

Comment: Reference to how to make that? or how to access an env file?

Comment: Also, you can use `bcrypt` to encrypt the password in the frontend post request and check if the password matches in the backend.